# Is it possible to stop the execution in debug mode on variable access/write?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

Is it possible to stop the execution in debug mode when a specified variable is modified?

Some debuggers have this capability, is that possible in Intellij debug mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as Péter Török said in a comment it is possible.

Run -> View Breakpoints -> Field Watchpoints -> Add..

or

right click on field -> Toggle Field Watchpoint

Comment: This works for class field (like described here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html#manage-breakpoints), but not for local variables.